# PHP mail function has stopped working

Tags: email

I have created a contact form that sends an email to the website administrator and to the person who filled out the contact form. It was working fine and I have just come back to it to do some more testing and it has stopped sending. To my knowledge I've not changed any of the code. I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Can someone help? Below is the code for the three files I'm using.

This is the contact form file:

```
<div id="contact-form" class="contact-form">

    <div class="rounded-box">

        <div class="rounded-box-title">

        <h3>Ask for a call back</h3>
        <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?>/images-default/br_next.png"/>

        </div><!-- .rounded-box-title -->

        <?php  
        $cf = array(); 

        if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){  
            $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];  
        ?>

        <div id="success" class="success"><?php echo ($cf['success']); ?></div>

        <script>
        $("#success").delay(6000).slideUp();
        </script>

        <?php            
        }
        ?>  

        <div class="required-text-line">
        <span class="required">*</span><span class="required-text">indicates required field</span>
        </div>      

        <form name="contact-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/example/contact-form-send.php" method="POST">

            <fieldset> 
            <label for="fname"><span class="required">*</span>First name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="return validateFirstName()" value="" />  
            <span class="error" id="fnameError" style="display: none;"></span>
            <script>
            $("#fname").blur(function(){
                $("#fnameError").delay(6000).slideUp();
            })                
            </script>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset> 
            <label for="lname"><span class="required">*</span>Last name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" onblur="return validateLastName()" value="" />  
            <span class="error" id="lnameError" style="display: none;"></span>
            <script>
            $("#lname").blur(function(){
                $("#lnameError").delay(6000).slideUp();
            })                
            </script>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>  
            <label for="email"><span class="required">*</span>Email:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="return validateEmail()" value="" /> 
            <span class="error" id="emailError" style="display: none;"></span>
            <script>
            $("#email").blur(function(){
                $("#emailError").delay(6000).slideUp();
            })                
            </script>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>  
            <label for="tel"><span class="required">*</span>Telephone:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" onblur="return validateTel()" value="" /> 
            <span class="error" id="telError" style="display: none;"></span>
            <script>
            $("#tel").blur(function(){
                $("#telError").delay(6000).slideUp();
            })                
            </script>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>  
            <label for="message"><span class="required">*</span>Message:</label></br>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" onblur="return validateMessage()" ></textarea> 
            <span class="error" id="messageError" style="display: none;"></span>
            <script>
            $("#message").blur(function(){
                $("#messageError").delay(6000).slideUp();
            })                
            </script>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="hiddenfield">  
            <label for="hidden"></label>
            <textarea name="hidden" id="hidden" ></textarea> 
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />                
            <script>
            $("form").submit(function(){        
                $(".error").delay(6000).slideUp();
            })
            </script>    
        </form>

        <?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?>      

    </div><!-- .rounded-box -->

</div><!-- .contact-form -->
```

This is the send PHP file:

```
<?php 

if( isset($_POST) ){ 

    if (empty($_POST ['hidden'])) { 

        $fname = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['fname']);
        $lname = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['lname']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['email']);
        $tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['tel']);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['message']);

        $to = "example@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Callback request";
        $body = "
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <header style='padding:10px'>
            <a href='http://example.com'>
            <img src='http://example.com/images-default/example-logo.png' alt='example.com'>
            </a>
            </header>
            <body style='border-top:2px solid #91448D;margin-top:15px'>
            <p>You have recieved an message through the callback request form on the website.</p>
            <p><strong>Name: </strong>{$fname} {$lname} </p>
            <p><strong>Email: </strong>{$email} </p>
            <p><strong>Telephone: </strong>{$tel} </p>
            <p><strong>Message: </strong>{$message}</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            ";
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: example <info@example.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: info@example.com' . "\r\n";

        mail (  //email to info@example.com
            $to,
            $subject,
            $body,
            $headers 
        );

        $subject2 = "Thanks for your enqiry";
        $body2 = "
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <header style='padding:10px'>
            <a href='http://example.com'>
            <img src='http://example.com/images-default/example-logo.png' alt='example.com'>
            </a>
            </header>
            <body style='border-top:2px solid #91448D;margin-top:15px'><br/>
            <p style='margin-bottom:1em'>Hi {$fname},<br/><br/>
            Thanks for enquiring about private maths tuition with <a href='http://example.com'>example.com</a>.<br/><br/>
            We'll get back to you within 24 hours for a chat about your child's learning needs.<br/><br/>
            Regards,<br/><br/>
            <strong>Kathy</strong><br/>
            <a href='http://example.com'>example.com</a> founder<br/>
            tel: 01582 472060<br/>
            email: <a href='mailto:info@example.com'>info@example.com</a></p>
            </body>
            </html>
            ";

        mail (  //email to enquiror
            $email,
            $subject2,
            $body2,
            $headers 
        );

        $success = "Thank you for your enquiry. We'll get back to you within 24 hours.";
        $returndata = array (
            'success' => $success
        );

        session_start();  
        $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}

?>
```

This is the javascript validation file:

```
function validateFirstName(){

    if (
        document.getElementById('fname').value == "") {
            document.getElementById('fnameError').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('fnameError').innerHTML = "Please enter your first name";
            return false;       
        } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('fnameError').style.display = "none";
        return true; 
    }
}

function validateLastName(){

    if (
        document.getElementById('lname').value == "") {
            document.getElementById('lnameError').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('lnameError').innerHTML = "Please enter your last name";
            return false;       
        } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('lnameError').style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
}

function validateEmail(){ 

    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (
        re.test(document.getElementById('email').value)){
            document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "none";
            return true;
            }
        else {
            if (
                document.getElementById('email').value == "") {
                    document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('emailError').innerHTML = "Please enter your email address";
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('emailError').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
                    return false;
                }
        }
}

function validateTel(){ 

    var re = /(((\+44)? ?(\(0\))? ?)|(0))( ?[0-9]{3,4}){3}/;

    if (
        re.test(document.getElementById('tel').value)){
            document.getElementById('telError').style.display = "none";
            return true;
            }
        else {
            if (
                document.getElementById('tel').value == "") {
                    document.getElementById('telError').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('telError').innerHTML = "Please enter your phone number";
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('telError').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('telError').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid phone number";
                    return false;
                }
        }
}

function validateMessage(){

    if (
        document.getElementById('message').value == "") {
            document.getElementById('messageError').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('messageError').innerHTML = "Please enter a message";
            return false;       
        } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('messageError').style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
}

function validateForm(){
    // Set error catcher
    var error = 0;
    // Check first name

    if(!validateFirstName(document.getElementById('fname').value)){
        document.getElementById('fnameError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
    }
    // Check last name
    if(!validateLastName(document.getElementById('lname').value)){
        document.getElementById('lnameError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
    }
    // Validate email
    if(!validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)){
        document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
    }
    // Validate phone number
    if(!validateTel(document.getElementById('tel').value)){
        document.getElementById('telError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
    }
    if(!validateMessage(document.getElementById('message').value)){
        document.getElementById('messageError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
    }
    if (
        !document.getElementById('hidden').value == "") {
        error++;
    }
    if(error > 0){
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not working"?  When you debug this, is the mail-sending code actually reached and executed?  Is there an error?  Is the SMTP server responding?  Is there an error in that?  Are the runtime values what you expect them to be when the code executes?  Is the mail being sent and just not being received on the other end?  Lots of things can go wrong here, and we can't debug it for you.

Comment: has your php version change?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not very advanced at coding. The mail() function does work because if I put a very simple mail() function in the page and reload the page, I receive an email. So I figure it is something to do with the code that is there. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: I was hoping it is something simple and obvious that I've missed...